# div does not register scolling event

Tags: html, razor, blazor

I have a simple div

```html
            <div class="flex-item middle" id="scrollable-element">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="company logo">
                </div>
                <div class="mainContent bodyhere">
                    <QT_Tagger.Shared.Details.Index._TopWelcome/>
                </div>
                <div class="mainContent bodyhere visibleOnMobile">
                    <QT_Tagger.Shared.Details.Index._OptionsMenuIndex id="2" />
                </div>
                <div class="mainContent bodyhere">
                    <QT_Tagger.Shared.Details.Index._HowItWorks/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It is the center part of my razor page, that scrolls upon overflow, while everything else in the page stays where it is:

```css
    .flex-item {
            flex: 1;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    
            .flex-item.middle {
                flex: 2;
                height: 98.5vh;
                overflow: scroll;
            }
```

Now I want to be alerted when the user starts scrolling, I did this:

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var scrollableElement = document.getElementById('scrollable-element');
        scrollableElement.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            console.log('Scrolled!');
        });
    });
```

But never is there anything logged into the console.
I believe it has something to do with the rest staying fix; because if I did this with the whole page, it would work. Only here doesnt it work;

and tips?

Comment: I would recommend this browser api instead of scroll https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: When it loads is there any content to scroll, I mean is there a movable bar? The scroll event won't fire if the children fit in the parent element.